# Analog to "sustainability"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

I asked a question on [english synonyms of "sustainability" alrady on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43611/were-there-any-other-synonyms-to-sustainability-before-the-80s). In Spanish, dictionaries and ngrams give out several options:

[image]

Comparing with the english ngrams chart I conclude *la sustentabilidad, la sostenibilidad* match sustainability? What's the difference between both terms?

More important, were *la persistencia, la tenacidad* used in a ecological/economical context before the 80/90s? Or is it similar to English, there existed no term for this problem, topic in spanish sciences? The rise of *la persistencia* in the ngrams chart looks suspicious to me, can someone explain this? Are three terms common for the problem of sustainability in Spanish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay IMO this is a tough one to understand if I put myself in the shoes of a non native speaker.

I'll try to explain:

Sustenabilidad and sostenibilidad roughly mean the same most of the time, but they have nunances between them that make them slightly differ in meaning.

You won't find **sustentabilidad** in the RAE but sostenabilidad is present:

> [sostenibilidad.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sostenabilidad)
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de sostenible.

Now, sustenabilidad comes from sustento which is in the RAE:

> [sustento.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sostenabilidad)
>
> 1. m. Mantenimiento, alimento.
> 2. m. Aquello que sirve para dar vigor y permanencia.
> 3. m. Sostén o apoyo.

To understand sostenibilidad we have to define the word in its meaning **sostenible**:

> [sostenible.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=sostenabilidad)
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un proceso: Que puede mantenerse por sí mismo, como lo hace, p. ej., un desarrollo económico sin ayuda exterior ni merma
>      de los recursos existentes.

**Sustentabilidad** is specific of a external source of support and maintenance. It means that the resources of survival or maintenance are external to it. Example: La sustentabilidad del humano depende del agua y alimento disponible. Example2: El sustento del niño viene de sus padres.

**Sostenibilidad** is specific to independence of maintenance. Of self survival (sort of). Means, more concretely the capacity of something to **sustain** itself. Example: Un bosque es sostenible solo si no hay peligros que amenacen su existencia.

Now here is an example that can illustrate both points and their difference at the same time:

**La sostenibilidad de una colonia de hormigas depende de su sustentabilidad.**

(Okay the example is not as good as I imagined it. But if someone has a better one feel free to edit the answer.)

Now for the terms **persistencia** and **tenacidad** is really hard to know if they where used in the 80/90s. But I found a work about Colombia that uses the word several times while describing the economical and social situation. Source: [**Colombia en el cambio de siglo**](http://www.nuso.org/upload/articulos/3089_1.pdf)

The two terms, **sostenibilidad** and **sustentabilidad** are widely used at this time to express environmental problems. And it has always been used for economical context since I can remember, when I was in school or highschool we always used this term in social studies or in biology for environment related problems.

Comment: I can't see the charts in spanish, I can only see the ones on the english page for some reason. I will see them when I get home and change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

*Sustentabilidad* and *sostenibilidad* match sustainability and are synonyms. As noun *sustentabilidad* is more common than *sostenibilidad*. Ej. *La nueva ley de sustentabilidad*

Variations of *sostenibilidad* are used as adjetives: ej: *Desarrollo sostenible*

*Persistencia* and *tenacidad* are not used as synonym.